# index and length must refer to a location within the string. parameter name length c# error while trying to save data in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008

index and length must refer to a location within the string. parameter name length error when i am trying to save data into the database i am using windows form application.. this is my code

```
if ((mode == Globale.OperationMode.ADD) && 
            (Globale.DocExist("tbl_OrderMain", "OrderNo", txtOrderNo.Text.Trim())))
{               
   [here i am getting error] 
   string NewNo =  Globale.FindOrderNo(txtOrderNo.Text.Trim().Substring( 0, 6));
   MessageBox.Show("Before you some body save " + txtOrderNo.Text + " now new No. is :" + NewNo, "Duplicat Doc No.");
   txtOrderNo.Text = NewNo;
}
```

Comment: The message seems to be pretty clear to me. Your txtOrderNo doesn't contain a text of 6 characters after the trimming. So you get the exception because you try to read 6 chars from position 0

Answer (score 1):

It seems that txtOrderNo.Text length is less than 6 character, that why its throwing an exception.

```
    if ((mode == Globale.OperationMode.ADD) && (Globale.DocExist("tbl_OrderMain", "OrderNo", txtOrderNo.Text.Trim())))
        {               
          //Put a check here
           string NewNo = string.Empty;
If(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOrderNo.Text.Trim()) && txtOrderNo.Text.Trim().Length >= 6)
    {
         NewNo =  Globale.FindOrderNo(txtOrderNo.Text.Trim().Substring( 0, 6));
    }
    else
    {   
         NewNo = //Assign it to some other value. 
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Before you some body save " + txtOrderNo.Text + " now new No. is :" + NewNo, "Duplicat Doc No.");
    txtOrderNo.Text = NewNo;
}
```

Comment: The first check for IsNullOrEmpty is useless. The Text property is never null and the second check is good also for empty strings.